# Please explain this solution to me (with picture)

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

[image]

This is my teacher's work on how to prove a limit statement using delta-epsilon. I understand everything except the where I circled it red. How did he get rid of the term sqrt (x-5) + 2 in the denominator? Where in the world did the zero come from?

Comment: In general, if $a,b,c >0$, we have ${a \over b+c} < {a \over c}$. This follows from $b+c > c$.

Comment: can i have an example please?

Comment: This is just about ordering of numbers. You understand that if the numbers are positive then $b+c > c$, right?

Comment: yes i get that part about b + c > c

Comment: And you understand that if $0 <x < y$ then ${1 \over y} < {1 \over x}$, right?

Comment: yes i do  get that too

Comment: Then you have $b+c >c$, hence ${1 \over b+c} < {1 \over c}$ and so (since $a\ge0$) ${a \over b+c} \le {a \over c}$. In your case you have $a=|x-9|$, $b=\sqrt{x-5}$ and $c=2$.

Comment: Minor point, it doesn't quite work. Suppose we are given a really silly $\epsilon$, like $\epsilon=10$. Then the choice $\delta=20$ is not good, for our function is not defined for some $x$ in the interval $|x-9|\lt 20$.

Comment: André's point is that $\sqrt{x-5}$ is only defined (in this context) for $x \ge 5$, so we need to restrict $\delta$ so that if $|x-9| < \delta$, then $x \ge 5$. (In particular, we need $\delta \le 4$.)

Answer (score 3):

Making the denominator smaller makes the fraction value larger.

(Sharing a pizza with less folks allows for larger slices)